# How to Access Parent Directory in Python

Tags: python, path, directory, parent, traversal

So I have a Python script that was given to me by a friend of mine, but I have no experience in Python. This is the code for it:

```
from os import path, chdir, listdir, mkdir, getcwd
from sys import argv
from zipfile import ZipFile
from time import sleep

#Defines what extensions to look for within the file (you can add more to this)
IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSIONS = ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.tif', '.tiff')

#Changes to the directory in which this script is contained
thisDir,_ = path.split(path.abspath(argv[0]))
chdir(thisDir)

#Lists all the files/folders in the directory
fileList = listdir('.')
for file in fileList:

    #Checks if the item is a file (opposed to being a folder)
    if path.isfile(file):

        #Fetches the files extension and checks if it is .docx
        _,fileExt = path.splitext(file)
        if fileExt == '.docx':

            #Creates directory for the images
            newDirectory = path.join(thisDir + "\Extracted Items", file + " - Extracted Items")
            if not path.exists(newDirectory):
                mkdir(newDirectory)

            currentFile = open(file, "r")
            for line in currentFile:
                print line

            sleep(5)



            #Opens the file as if it is a zipfile
            #Then lists the contents
            try:
                zipFileHandle = ZipFile(file)
                nameList = zipFileHandle.namelist()

                for archivedFile in nameList:
                    #Checks if the file extension is in the list defined above
                    #And if it is, it extracts the file
                    _,archiveExt = path.splitext(archivedFile)
                    if archiveExt in IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSIONS:
                        zipFileHandle.extract(archivedFile, newDirectory)
                    if path.basename(archivedFile) == "document.xml":
                        zipFileHandle.extract(archivedFile, newDirectory)
                    if path.basename(archivedFile) == "document.xml.rels":
                        zipFileHandle.extract(archivedFile, newDirectory)
            except:
                pass
```

For the line that reads `newDirectory = path.join(thisDir + "\Extracted Items", file + " - Extracted Items")`

I want to modify that to access the parent directory of `thisDir` and then create the `\Extracted Items` folder. Does anyone know what the best way to access the parent directory is in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent directory using the `split` function from the `os.path` module.

```
from os.path import dirname, split, isdir
parent_dir = lambda x: split(x)[0] if isdir(x) else split(dirname(x))[0]
```

As you do not have experience in Python, a short explanation of the code:
The `lambda` statement defines an *inline* -function. Within this function, the *ternary condition* first evaluates if the given path `x` is a directory. If it applies, the path is splitted using the `split` function. If the path `x` is **not** a directory, first the directory name of the path is calculated and then the path is splitted.
Splitting a path looks like this: `C:\Foo\Bar\file.spam => (C:\Foo\Bar\, file.spam)`

Now see what's happening when calling the function:

```
path = r"C:\Foo\Bar\file.spam"
print "Parent directory of " + path + ":", parent_dir(path)
```

> Parent directory of C:\Foo\Bar\file.spam: C:\Foo\

Note: In my opinion the parent directory of a file is the parent-directory of the directory of the file. If you don't define it like this, your function could also look like this:

```
from os.path import dirname, split, isdir
parent_dir = lambda x: split(x)[0] if isdir(x) else dirname(x)
```

Comment: So from the the originally posted code, I would not have to import anything as I already have `from os import path` included, correct? And as that code applies to me, would it be like `parent_dir = lambda thisDir: split(thisDir)[0] if isdir(thisDir) else split(dirname(thisDir))[0]` then `newDirectory = path.join(parent_dir + "\Extracted Items", file + " - Extracted Items")`?

Comment: Ah, so I should use `parent_dir = lambda x: split(x)[0] if isdir(x) else dirname(x)` as my definition of parent directory is the immediate parent directy of the folder I am currently working in?

Comment: Yes, if you only use `dirname(x)` you'll recieve the folder the file `x` is in.  And yes, path is already included.
If you do not import the functions directly, you can access them using the *point notation*.
`parent_dir = lambda x: path.split(x)[0] if path.isdir(x) else path.dirname(x)`. In your last code snipped, you need to **call** the function to activate it and give it the path to work on:
`newDirectory = path.join(parent_dir(currentDirectory), "Extracted Items", file + "- Extracted Items")`.

Comment: Note that `path.join` does automatically add `\ `  between the arguments passed to it, so you can replace `path.join(thisDir + "\Extracted Items", file, ..)` with `path.join(thisDir, "Extracted Items", file, ..)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import os.path,sys
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\','/')
PARENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, os.pardir))
```